# How can I access a variable in Jquery and use its value in another external .js file ? The variable is $generatedP

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to access in a different .js file the value inside $generatedP and display it

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
 var $buttonValue = $(".value_generate"); 
 var $divValue = $(".generated_value");
 var $generatedP = $(".generated_p");
 var $valueInput2 = $(".value_input_2");
 var $submitPages2 = $(".submit_pages_2");
 function valueGenerator(value) {
  var valueString="";
  var lettersNumbers = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  for(var i = 0; i < value; i++) 
   valueString += lettersNumbers.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()* lettersNumbers.length));
   return valueString; 
 }//generate string
    $buttonValue.click(function generate() {
  var $key = valueGenerator(12);
  $generatedP.html($key);//display generated string
 });
 $submitPages2.click(function() {
 if($valueInput2.val() == $generatedP.text() ){
  alert("you are logged in website");
 } else {
  alert("please check again the value");
  return false;
 }//check value if true/false
 });
```

I am new to jquery

Comment: Try defining it outside `$(document).ready()...` but in this case you will have to refer js file after the js file containing above code

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

Create a namespace inside the jQuery object:

```
$.myGlobalNamespace = {};
$.myGlobalNamespace.generatedPvalue = "something";
```

Define an object at the window level:

```
window.myGlobalNamespace = {};
window.myGlobalNamespace.generatedPvalue = "something";
```

Just be sure to use a sensible name for the namespace object.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the behavior doing client-side checking with **localStorage**, or you can simply use **sessionStorage**. Variable $generatedP will be available in **page1** and **page2**. Hope it helps!

**PAGE 1:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <script type = "text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
 var $generatedP = "27.23.10";
 sessionStorage.setItem('myVar', $generatedP);
 window.location.href = "page2.html";
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PAGE 2:** to access the variable just use the **getItem** method and that is all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
 var data = sessionStorage.getItem('myVar');
 alert(data);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```